# My R script not picking up all the files in the folder

Tags: r

My R script is trying to aggregate excel spreadsheets that are in different folders within the Concerned Files folder (shown in the directory below) and putting all the data into one master file. However, the script is randomly selecting files to copy information from and when i run the code, the following error shows so i am assuming this is why it's not choosing every file in the folder?

```
all_some_data <- rbind(all_some_data, temp) 
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

The whole code:

```
#list of people's name it has to search the folders for. For our purposes, i am only taking one name
managers <- c("Name")
#directory of all the files
directory = 'C:/Users/Username/OneDrive/Desktop/Testing/Concerned Files/'

#Create an empty dataframe
all_HR_data <-
setNames(
data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0)),
c("Employee", "ID", "Overtime", "Regular", "Total", "Start", "End", "Manager")
)
str(files)
#loop through managers to get time sheets and then add file to combined dataframe
for (i in managers){
#a path to find all the extract files
 files <-
 list.files(
  path = paste(directory, i, "/", sep = ""),
  pattern = "*.xls",
  full.names = FALSE,
  recursive = FALSE
    )

   #for each file, get a start and end date of period, remove unnecessary columns, rename columns and add manager name
for (j in files){
temp <- read_excel(paste(directory, i, "/", j, sep = ""), skip = 8)

 #a bunch of manipulations with the data being copied over. Code not relevant to the problem

all_some_data <- rbind(all_some_data, temp)
     }
}
```

Comment: I imagine we'd have to know what files are in that directory to know which ones are or aren't being read, let alone why or why not. Also, keep in mind the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance: if the issue is just with recognizing files in a directory, we probably don't need to run a script that requires SQL commands. Narrowing the issue down will help you debug

Comment: They are all in a standard xls format. I have edited my code also. Thanks!

Comment: First guess would be the columns are not all the same, e.g. maybe start before column I (skip = 8)

Comment: Okay, but you said that all the files aren't being read, and made it sound like an issue of recognizing files in a directory. But we don't have access to your directory. Is that in fact the issue, or is it with reading the files? Does your call to `list.files` get all the files you expect it to?

Comment: Yes, when i do view(files) - all titles of files do get recognized

Comment: And all the paths you get with `paste(directory, i, "/", j, sep = "")` match the actual files? It might be safer to use `file.path` to create paths. But if all your files are being recognized, I don't understand your description of the problem, because it seems to hinge on that

Comment: You may run into problems ending a string with /, I would reccomend moving the trailing / into your list.files path like so paste0(directory, "/", i, "/")

Comment: I tried the / suggestion as well as the skip but nope. Not sure where the problem is occurring since the error in rbind is the only error thats being shown to me

Comment: As a troubleshooting measure, you could add something like `print(temp[1:2, ])` before the line that gives you the error. I'm guessing it will stop at a mismatched spreadsheet.

Comment: The error "numbers of columns of arguments do not match" sounds like one of the files does not match the expected format.  See markhogue comments concerning adding a print statement.

Comment: Many thanks Markhogue and Dave2e, it does look like some files have an unnecessary column which i will delete. Will investigate for others. Can you put it as answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Sorry to clarify, one file has an unnecessary column and the code stops picking up files after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is an extra column in one or more of your files.

A potential solution along with a performance improvement is to use the `bind_rows` function from the dplyr package.  This function is more fault tolerant than the base R `rbind`.

Wrap you loop up with lapply statement and then use `bind_rows` on the entire list of dataframes in one statement.

```
output <-lapply(files, function(j) {
      temp <- read_excel(paste(directory, i, "/", j, sep = ""), skip = 8)

       #a bunch of manipulations with the data being copied over. 
       # Code not relevant to the problem

      temp  #this is the returned value to the list
  })
all_some_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(output)
```